# Wordpress page id not working on selected pages

Tags: css, wordpress, flexslider

I am trying to remove the slider from certain pages and it removes just fine except for one page that is running Easy Digital Downloads in the background. It is page id 102 in the below code. I can not get that page to remove the slider. This is the page https://psycheseminars.com/downloads/spirit-salt-lake-city/

```
body.page-id-12 .flexslider,
body.page-id-98 .flexslider,
body.page-id-99 .flexslider,
body.page-id-100 .flexslider,
body.page-id-102 .flexslider {
display: none;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The reason it is not working as you expect is because that page is actually a **post**. To change the element on that post you need to use `.postid-###`

The following CSS should remove the slider on that post.

```
.postid-102 .flexslider {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: @Lara Don't forget to mark your question as answered